# How to get form submit button to do update action as opposed to create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, button

I have created an edit page, very similar to my new page. However I want the submit button to call the update action of the related model, rather than the create action. This is probably very easy to do but I haven't figured out how to accomplish it.

Generally my buttons just look like this:

```
<%= f.submit('Text-of-button', :class => "button") %>
```

The class is included so the correct CSS is applied to the button. I heard RoR was smart enough to know if the submit should be an edit or a new, but it doesn't appear to be. I also tried forcing the controller and action to no success:

```
<%= f.submit('Update', :class => "button", :controller => 'location', :action => 'update') %>
```

I've seen people use button_to and include all the necessary information inside the button. but that seems messy when I have all the information I want on the form. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you don't need template for edit form if nothing special.

Just use create form and use `form_for @instance`.

`form_for` will judge the instance and arrange form path automatically. If the instance is not persisted, it will point to `#create`. If the instance is a persisted object in db, it will point to `#udpate` automatically.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following, my form_fors always declare a new instance I think.. and I'm filling the values manually with the passed @location for each form field (location being my model): `<%= #Form Builder
form_for :location, url: locations_path do |f|  
%>` are you saying I can just do `form_for @location` Is it possible for this to build the form for me? I tried that and it said something about expecting an `$end` at the end of my page do I still need the `do |f|`? I tried that as well and when I hit submit it says no route match [Put] /locations. Sorry.. fairly new to RoR

Comment: The instance is not created in form but controller. You prepare an instance in controller and the view eat it. If in #edit you find a record from db and then render the form, `form_for` will know this is an edit form because the instance is not new. For other questions, better to check Rails guide, too much basic stuff.

Comment: I see what you were saying now you also have to pass the instance, otherwise the method won't go to the right url... the full answer is `form_for @location, url: location_path(@location) do |f|`

Comment: @Andrew, actually you don't need to define url in form, Rails is smart enough to know how to generate the path according to the object(say persisted or not) and the routes. I get used to this style :)

Comment: I see, I could just do `form_for @location do |f|`